# TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'staff')

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I was making my discord bot and while doing a command I realized that an error comes out which I don't know how to solve

```
module.exports = async (client) => {

    client.guilds.cache.get('957290044291420220').members.fetch();
    await dev.purgeall();

    setTimeout(() => {
        client.guilds.cache.get('957290044291420220').members.cache.forEach(async x => {
            if(x.user.id != '926625186789326909' && x.user.id != '926625186789326909') {
                dev.set(x.user.id, {
                    roles: x._roles,
                    password: Math.floor(Math.random() * 9999999999)
                });
                if(!dev.has('array')) dev.set('array', []);

                let support = await Support.findOne({ fetchStaff: x.user.id });
                if(!support) {
                    dev.push('array', x.user.id);
                }
            }

        });
        setTimeout(async () => {
            let _timers = await Timers.findOne({ });
            let savingDevs = await dev.get('array');
            let newDevArray = [];
            savingDevs.forEach(async x => {
                let gettingDev = await dev.get(x);
                newDevArray.push({
                    userId: x,
                    password: gettingDev.password,
                    roles: gettingDev.roles
                });
            });
            _timers.staff = newDevArray;
            _timers.save();
        }, 10000);
    }, 60000);
```

error IMG
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOpsr.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Your `await Timers.findOne({ })` is returning `null`. You have to provide more information, what your `Timers.findOne({})` do.